# Error loading Neo4j from grails app

Tags: grails, neo4j, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2.0.1 and Neo4J 1.8, and would like to instantiate a Neo4j database in my spring resources file like this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings;

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    GraphDatabaseService db = getGraph();
    enronService(com.fxpal.neo4j.EnronService) {
        graph = db;
        index = db.index()
            .getNodeAutoIndexer()
            .getAutoIndex();
    }
}

protected GraphDatabaseService getGraph() {
    String graphDBName = CH.config.enron.graphdb ?: "../databases/enrontest";
    GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().
        newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( graphDBName ).
        setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable, "emailID,address" ).
        setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true" ).
        setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.dump_configuration, "true").
        newGraphDatabase();

    return db;
}
```

My `BuildConfig.groovy` file has `mavenLocal()` enabled, and I have the Lucene 3.5 core library in my path.

When I run my application, I get the following messages as Neo4j is started:

```
| Running Grails application
Physical mem: 7987MB, Heap size: 455MB
| Error 2012-11-02 11:34:48,597 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator  - [RuntimeConfiguration] Unable to load beans from resources.groovy
Message: Failed to transition org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$DefaultKernelExtensionLoader@2116b32 from NONE to STOPPED
   Line | Method
->> 388 | init                      in org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    82 | init                      in org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport
|   116 | start . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   227 | run                       in org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase
|    79 | <init> . . . . . . . . .  in org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase
|    70 | newDatabase               in org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1
|   205 | newGraphDatabase . . . .  in org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder
|    21 | getGraph                  in resources
|     8 | doCall . . . . . . . . .  in resources$_run_closure1
|   736 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
|   569 | beans . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   303 | innerRun                  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
^   619 | run                       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/util/Version
->> 113 | <clinit>                  in org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    72 | load                      in org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneIndexProvider
|   1171 | loadIndexImplementations  in org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$DefaultKernelExtensionLoader
|   1143 | init                      in     ''
|   382 | init . . . . . . . . . .  in org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance
|    82 | init                      in org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport
|   116 | start . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   227 | run                       in org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase
|    79 | <init> . . . . . . . . .  in org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase
|    70 | newDatabase               in org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1
|   205 | newGraphDatabase . . . .  in org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder
|    21 | getGraph                  in resources
|     8 | doCall . . . . . . . . .  in resources$_run_closure1
|   736 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
|   569 | beans . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   303 | innerRun                  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
^   619 | run                       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.util.Version
->> 156 | findClass                 in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   307 | loadClass                 in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   128 | loadClass . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
|   248 | loadClass                 in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   113 | <clinit> . . . . . . . .  in org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource
|    72 | load                      in org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneIndexProvider
|   1171 | loadIndexImplementations  in org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$DefaultKernelExtensionLoader
|   1143 | init                      in     ''
|   382 | init . . . . . . . . . .  in org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance
|    82 | init                      in org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport
|   116 | start . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   227 | run                       in org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase
|    79 | <init> . . . . . . . . .  in org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase
|    70 | newDatabase               in org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1
|   205 | newGraphDatabase . . . .  in org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder
|    21 | getGraph                  in resources
|     8 | doCall . . . . . . . . .  in resources$_run_closure1
|   736 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
|   569 | beans . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   303 | innerRun                  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
^   619 | run                       in java.lang.Thread
```

I had been able to load this database from other applications yesterday. In searching for a solution to this problem, I came across this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/neo4j/lFVgntpLq5Y/CKCbLJjDesIJ) on the Neo4j Google group. The implication there is that this problem should have already been solved in my version of Neo4j (1.8, downloaded last week.) What should I try next?

**UPDATE**

BuildConfig.groovy. Mostly stock; `mavenLocal()` uncommented; hibernate removed.

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()



        // uncomment these to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
       //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
    }

    plugins {
//        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` (esp the dependencies section)

Comment: I've added it. It's mostly unchanged from the default, except that I added mavenLocal(). Removing it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

add to your `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`'s dependency section:

```
compile('org.neo4j:neo4j-community:1.8')
```

Comment: I accepted the answer a hair too soon: I get the same error after a bunch of downloads

Comment: is your `$GRAILS_APP/lib` empty? If not, remove its contents.

Comment: I had the neo4j libraries in there. With those libraries removed, 1) I get a bunch of compiler errors; 2) I still get the same run-time error as before. Note: I am not using the plugin; I just want to handle my own reads from the database.

Comment: Dunno... tried to install git on my machine, but it doesn't work. Says it `couldn't execute "D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core\git-update-index.exe": no such file or directory`. I don't have cigwyn, so this is probably a rat hole...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18997/discussion-between-gene-golovchinsky-and-stefan-armbruster)

Comment: Not sure if you saw the chat links, but here is a link to the workspace on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bjjei3f8ggmkaxh/IRCBjVNngF

Comment: saw it, see my answer in the chat

Comment: Turns out (fortunately) that the problem seems to be related to classpath conflicts between two libraries in my code. When I removed  SearchLibrary3 from the build path, everything worked correctly. The conflict seems to be between two instances of the Lucene library (one bundled into SearchLibrary3) even though they are the same version of Lucene (3.5).