# How To Use Grails With GrapheneDB

Tags: grails, neo4j

Has anyone used Graphenedb for a Grails project? I'm trying to create a Neo4J app to be hosted in Appfog which I'll connect to a Neo4J DB in GrapheneDB, but I can't seem to even figure out how to start Neo4J in Grails. I've done the following:

1. Created new Grails 2.3.5 project in Grails Tool Suite
2. In BuildConfig, removed hibernate reference then added:

   repositories { mavenRepo 'http://m2.neo4j.org/releases'

   plugins {compile ":neo4j:1.1.1" //followed the Grails Neo4J GORM instructions

   compile("org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:1.6") //also tried 2.0.0
3. In DataSource added:

   grails { neo4j {
               type = "rest"
               location = "xxx.sb01.stations.graphenedb.com:xxxx/db/data"
4. Created domain class with static mapWith = "neo4j" and generated controller and view

Whatever I do, I get errors:

Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:jar:xxx in grailsCentral

or

Compilation error: startup failed: Compile error during compilation with javac..

Other people had problems with Neo4J with Grails:

[Error loading Neo4j from grails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201322/error-loading-neo4j-from-grails-app)

[grails unable to connect to neo4j datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658727/grails-unable-to-connect-to-neo4j-datastore)

Questions:

1. Is there a tutorial on how to set up Neo4j rest on Grails ?
2. Is it better to use Play framework than Grails for Neo4J to begin with ? There seems to be more examples for building Neo4J apps in Scala than Grails. http://www.neo4j.org/develop/scala

Answer (score 1):

I'm Alberto from [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com).

I'm aware that you seem to be having a compilation error. I'm not familiar with Grails so I can't really help you with that.

I believe your configuration snippet for DataSource won't work because connecting to GrapheneDB instances requires supplying authentication credentials.

I'm not sure if you can supply the credentials embedded in the URL like this:

```
grails {
    neo4j {
        type = "rest"
        location = "http://username:password@fqdn:port/db/data/"
    }
}
```

Or if you have to provide username and password as separate config parameters:

```
grails {
    neo4j {
        type = "rest"
        location = "fqdn:port/db/data/"
        login = "login"
        password = "password" 
    }
}
```

If you manage to get past your compilation error, would you care to share the steps you went through to get it working? I would like to include them in the docs for anyone looking to connect their Grails app with GrapheneDB.

Alberto.

Answer (score 1):

There is small demo application at https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4jsample that I verified to work with GrapheneDB.

The trick is to use environment variables `NEO4_HOST`, `NEO4J_USER`, `NEO4J_LOGIN` and `NEO4J_PASSWORD` to specify the remote database and use `type=rest` in `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy`.

Please be aware that you get a `ClassNotFoundExecption` if you use forked mode for Grails 2.3.x. The workaround is switch off forked mode for run environment.

Comment: What's the proper syntax for NEO4J_USER, etc in Datasource.groovy? I tried Alberto's suggestions and also tried putting NEO4J_USER = "user", etc under environments but still failed to get to GrapheneDB.

Answer (score 0):

@jun yoga Syntax should be like this

export NEO4J_HOST="" #e.g.neo4jsample.sb01.stations.graphenedb.com"

export NEO4J_LOGIN=""#REST USERNAME

export NEO4J_PASSWORD=""#REST PASSWORD

export NEO4J_PORT=""#xxxxx

It should be typed in terminal if you used linux. It is System environment variable not application environment :)